# How to tell Amazon Alexa not to suggest or announce movies to me

Tags: alexa

Alexa just flashed that I had a notification. When I asked what my notifications were, the device started telling me about a new Timothee Chalamet movie. I don't want the device to suggest movies to me. **I don't see anything in the Alexa app Notifications settings to turn  movie suggestions off.** How would that be done? I do want Amazon shopping and severe weather notifications, so **I don't want to turn off notifications globally**.

Comment: Try telling it not to give you new movie notifications.  I havent tried it, it might work.

Comment: That was the very first thing I tried :-)    Alexa told me to go to the Settings in the Alexa app and turn off notifications.

Comment: From a google search:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ref_=hp_left_v4_sib&nodeId=GW65E37ZG4L9BW3P    Let us know if it worked.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop  I've already let you know in the question that it did not work. There is no subsection beneath notification settings that applies to movie suggestions, not as far as I can tell.  I will bold the sentence.

Comment: Another option you can try is to post to this forum:  https://uk.amazonforum.com/s/topic/0TO4P000000t6mSWAQ/general-echo-alexa

Comment: Also, you can try shutting off "news" if that is one of the notification options.

Comment: I suppose "unplug it" isn't the option you're looking for?

Comment: @FreeMan True, that would be worse than setting notifications off globally.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

According to "people on the internet"`[citation unlikely]`, Amazon is supposedly losing a lot of money on Alexa. As a result they are deploying these tricks trying to advertise more services that they hope will bring in more usage, which somehow might lead to more revenue. So Alexa responses are now polluted with "By the way, I can ..." kinds of suggestions.

The best you can do at this time is open the Alexa app, navigate to More+, then Notification preferences, then step through each of the pages deciding on whether or not you want to receive those particular messages.  That will help reduce, but not eliminate, some of the unwanted messages.